# Unity OnMouseEnter() or OnMouseOver() not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make an Inventory System in Unity, so I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=We1ab6yHrwI), but the functions `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseOver` are not working.

I tried everything like 3d colliders with `z-value` of 100, with trigger and not trigger, and also I checked if the `Physics.queriesHitTriggers` is `true`, but nothing works. Do you have any easy tips?

Not with raycasting... I'm quite new and don't understand this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.Please post the code you wrote

Answer (score 3):

- Try adding a box collider or box collider 2d
- Try adding  an rigidbody besides the collider and you can do it kinematic
- Try adding add a EventSystem if you are using canvas ui
- And verify that it does not have an object like a canvas blocking the camera raycast.

good luck.

Comment: Could you explain how raycasts work? Sorry but I'm quite new to Unity.

Comment: but I think I'll do it with  bounds of a box collider and check if the mouse position is in this collider.

Comment: The rigidbody did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The thing I found out is that OnMouseOver only works in the Game tab and not working in the Scene tab :)

Answer (score 0):

The GameObject you're trying to use mouse with, needs to have at least one component that is a rayccast target. an Image or SpriteRendrer should do it.

Comment: it has an Image and one boxcollider.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier and cleaner to use Unity UI System to make Inventory, Just Create Canvas, Image inside of it and add EventTrigger component to that Image object, and modify events inside of it in the inspector, add any functions you want on any event it supports it, it is much cleaner solution. Try this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZpq46W4xo4
U can do whatever you want with this system, just a little bit of thinking and planing your own Inventory Req...
Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to enable the old input manager in the project settings to make `ohnMouseOver` etc. work:

[image]